# How to set a user environmental variable in .profile

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables

I set an environmental variable for user on CentOS by simply:

1.) Logging in with the user

2.) Going to their home directory `cd ~` and creating a file `.profile`

3.) Putting the following in the `.profile` file:

```
export APP="dev"
```

However, when I:

```
echo $APP
```

It is blank. I have tried closing my SSH session and retying, still the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.profile` is only read for login shells. Either use `~/.bashrc` for all bash shells, or `~/.ssh/rc` for SSH connections only.

Comment: Even putting it in my `~/.bashrc` I can't get the value from PHP using `getenv()`, always comes back `false`. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to restart your shell (relogin) or just simply execute `source ~/.bashrc` or the equivalent `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Justin: Are you running the PHP code from the logged-in shell?

Answer (score 0):

you can place `myenv.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` directory

in myenv.sh you can have the following line

```
export APP="dev"
```

it is working